# Connection string in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, connection-string

I’m a student. And this is my first production level project. I’m developing a WPF application using Entity Framework, which will be running only on a tab. I have problem in choosing a database. Since this application is going to run only on one device and cloud database cannot be used, what would be the best option?

If I use mssql the connection string in my development environment and production environment differs. Am I wrong? If I’m right what would be the solution for having a connection string that works identically in both environments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you always end up with a different connection string for development (ex: without password) and for production (ex: long password).

C# handles this with `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="yourname" connectionString="..." providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And then you'll add a transformation file that changes certain values of your `App.config` depending on the environment where you'll deploy it.

Typically there is an `App.Release.config` file that updates the connectionString when built in Release mode (versus Debug mode)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="yourname"
      connectionString="productionConnectionStringHere"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As to which database you're going to use: It doesn't really matter. Have a look at [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/). Or [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/) if you don't have tabular data.

Comment: How to determine the production connection string

Comment: Connectionstrings differ from database to database. You'll find them all documented on [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)